# upload audio to server PHP android

Tags: php, android, audio, upload, mp3

i had a problem while uploading an MP3 file to server using android + Php
am using android studio 
everything is work perfectly just when upload is finished i cannot find my file at server side

my Layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.uploadfile.milad.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/upload"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Upload"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="144dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="216dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/upload"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />
```

my Mainactivity code :

```
package com.uploadfile.milad;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressBar progressBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    checkPermissions();

    Log.w("LOG", Environment.getDataDirectory().toString());
    Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            /*final String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/pdf.pdf";
            upload(path);*/

        }
    });
}

public void upload(String path){

    Upload upload = new Upload(MainActivity.this, path);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    Log.w("LOG","file exist: " + upload.fileExist());

    upload.run(new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            Log.w("LOG","response: " + responseBody.toString() + " status code: " + statusCode);
            if(statusCode == 200){ //responseBody.toString().equals("success")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Suecced",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getMax());
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Failed: " + error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {
            double percentage = (double)bytesWritten/(double)totalSize * 100;
            progressBar.setProgress ((int)percentage);
            Log.w("LOG","Percentage: "  + percentage);
            super.onProgress(bytesWritten, totalSize);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0 && data != null) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final String path = data.getData().getPath().replace(":","/").replace("document","storage");
            Log.w("LOG","FILE PATH: " + path);
            upload(path);
        }
    }
}

public void checkPermissions(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},0);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
}

}
```

my upload class :

```
package com.uploadfile.milad;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.location.Address;
import android.util.Log;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import com.loopj.android.http.ResponseHandlerInterface;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.ResponseHandler;



public class Upload {

private static String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/edsa-proj/test%20lab/up/upload.php", KEY = "uploaded_file";
private String fileAddress;
private File file;

private AsyncHttpClient httpClient;
private Context context;
private RequestParams params;

public Upload(Context context, String FileAddress){
    this.fileAddress = FileAddress;
    this.context = context;
    httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    params = new RequestParams();
    file  = new File(FileAddress);
}

public boolean fileExist(){
    if(file.exists())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
/*returns
   true if file is exist
   false if file not exist
* */
public boolean run(ResponseHandlerInterface handler){
    if(putFileParam(file)) {
        httpClient.post(context, URL, params, handler);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
/*returns
   true if file is exist
   false if file not exist
* */
private boolean putFileParam(File file)
{
    try {
        params.put(KEY, file);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.w("LOG_UPLOAD", e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

and php code :

```
<?php

$file_path = "uploads/";
$KEY = 'uploaded_file';
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES[$KEY]['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$KEY]['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
 ?>
```

i used replace in string just for testing 
my problem is when i choose a file after uploading is finished i cannot find mp3 file on foolder uploads 
i can't figure where is the problem 
thnx in advance

Comment: Have you chmoded correctly the destination folder? Any chance file is being saved withou extension, or with hidden atribs?

Comment: my server is on windows 10 
permissions are Ok 
Work fine with images

Comment: i tested on a linux server and works perfectly when you have a hardcoded path, i mean, if i allow `final String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/pdf.pdf";` and `upload(path);` on the button listener. But if i give user the option to locate a file to upload then i get error: `W/LOG_UPLOAD: java.io.FileNotFoundException`. As i said: when path is hardcoded, it works perfectly, the file is uploaded to the desired folder on server, it keeps the original name and is able to be read.

Comment: try it on mp3 file plz

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct if you hardcode the absolute path of the file you want to upload. It's working perfect.

Your code and logic are alright, besides working here with absolute path (but it's probably something minor to solve this). The conclusion is: the matters you are facing has to do with your server configuration. I would suggest you investigate something behind user accounts, rights and permissions (to upload files, to write server side). If having problems with it, open another question here at StackOverflow. This present one is done.